# Thymeleaf extras detects that the spring version is not compatible

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I tried to build my spring boot web application and create jar file to deploy it on the dedicated server. When I build it using IDE (in my case Intellij Idea) all works fine. But when I try to execute jar and get pages which use thymeleaf extras tags (like sec:authorize) I recieve an exception like this

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.ConfigurationException: The Spring-version-specific infrastructure could not create utility for the specific version of Spring being used. Currently only Spring 6.x or newer is supported.
        at org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity6.util.SpringVersionSpecificUtils.<clinit>(SpringVersionSpecificUtils.java:74) ~[pastebin.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity6.util.SpringSecurityContextUtils.getAuthenticationObject(SpringSecurityContextUtils.java:127) ~[pastebin.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity6.auth.AuthUtils.getAuthenticationObject(AuthUtils.java:102) ~[pastebin.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity6.dialect.processor.AuthorizeAttrProcessor.isVisible(AuthorizeAttrProcessor.java:67) ~[pastebin.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.AbstractStandardConditionalVisibilityTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractStandardConditionalVisibilityTagProcessor.java:61) ~[pastebin.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74) ~[pastebin.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95) ~[pastebin.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633) ~[pastebin.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1314) ~[pastebin.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.thymeleaf.engine.OpenElementTag.beHandled(OpenElementTag.java:205) ~[pastebin.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateModel.process(TemplateModel.java:136) ~[pastebin.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:661) ~[pastebin.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1103) ~[pastebin.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1077) ~[pastebin.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.thymeleaf.spring6.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:372) ~[pastebin.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.thymeleaf.spring6.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:192) ~[pastebin.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
...
```

As you can see spring considers that the version of some dependencies is lower than 6. But in my pom.xml I use spring-boot-starter-parent which should provide right versions and I believe it does.

pom.xml

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>pastebin</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>pastebin Maven Webapp</name>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>18</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>18</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
                <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
                <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
                <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring6</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
                <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
                <version>9.37.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <version>2.16.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                <version>33.0.0-jre</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
                <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
                <version>9.2.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>1.18.30</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <version>42.7.2</version>
            </dependency>

            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
                <version>5.10.2</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                <version>5.10.2</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                <artifactId>hamcrest</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.12.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>18</source>
                    <target>18</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <addResources>true</addResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.vladpochuev.config.PastebinApplication</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>pastebin</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

I checked maven build with
`mvn dependency:tree`
and didn't find any conflicts. If I would remove thymeleaf extras dependency there wouldn't be any of issues except of losing some related functionality. So I think it leads to wrong execution.